# How to track users actions on a form in my website

Tags: 7, forms

I read some post about "how to track..." but i didn't find my answer. I don't want to track the [user loggin](http://drupal.org/project/user_stats) or how many time a user click on a link but what i would like to accomplish is:

- Track my user (anonymous or authenticated) to know if they failed to fulfill a form (failed = quit before submitting the form)
- Have a rate about each form who tell me, for example : 30% of users who begun the register form, stopped before submiting
- And more, knowing which fields were fulfilled before he quit.

My purpose is to help me to:

- Understand which process, forms are misunderstood in my website
- Maybe, knowing exactly which fields in my form (which label) are misunderstood (thanks to the fact that i could know which fields were empty when he quit)

I'm not a pro of `Google analytic` but i don't think so he can do that.
What is the better approach for me to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

PHP saves data once you click the submit button, so finding which fields they filled before quitting might not be that straight forward. 
But you can always see how many times form was loaded and number of submitted entries to find the ratio.

Comment: Yes you're right, for the fields filled or not, i was thinking more about a Javascript solution (with keyup, keydown to know if someone had written something in)